# Ubuntu 18.04 Epson ET-3700 Won't Print from Browser

Tags: printing, pdf, epson, html

I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux. I have successfully installed an Epson ET-3700 printer using these instructions:  https://tutorialforlinux.com/2019/06/19/driver-epson-et-3700-ubuntu-18-04-how-to-download-install-2/

If I select "Print a Test Page" it will print a beautiful test page and it prints from LibreOffice.

The problem is that it won't print a PDF from the pdf viewer or an html file like an email. I read the post on this site ([Canon printer won't print PDF files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425947/canon-printer-wont-print-pdf-files)) about the Canon printer doing the same. Was really discouraged to see the input of others with god-like Linux powers who ended up being equally discouraged. It's looking bad for the good guys here.

In my feeble attempts to get this thing to work, I successfully installed the printer and clicked on the PDF viewer printer icon.  A "print job in progress" message would show but was soon followed with a "print job cancelled" message.

I tried several other solutions, deleting all printers, reinstalling, adding the printer as a network printer, hardwiring the printer to the computer, extracting the downloaded .deb drivers from the folders and using terminal to install them, etc.

I even downloaded the pdf file and then selected "print as image." Again, I'd get the "print in progress" then "print cancelled" messages.

The one time I got it to print from the network but it came out in Klingon.  Total machine language.

The Epson support site for Linux drivers is pretty funny. It's all in Japanese.  Even when you select English, it's all in Japanese.

Your input is welcome.  I print a lot of emails and attachments and I'd hate to abandon a $380 printer if there isn't a solution.

UPDATE: Nope.  Doesn't work anymore.  My fault, I foolishly entered code in the terminal to clear some caches and evidently ended up clearing out the printer.

The printer works through the network but will only print a downloaded document or through LibreOffice, it won't print from the web (email) or the PDF viewer.

The scanner software, imagescan, is installed but neither imagescan nor simple-scan can detect the scanner. "No devices found."

I think this noob needs help configuring the scanner software to access the network IP address.

Comment: SOLVED thanks to Daniel Faulkner's May 28, 2019 answer to "Print job cancelled at the printer." I went to the printer settings, selected "Additional Printer Settings," highlighted the printer that I knew worked, clicked on the "Add" button and then went to "Location of Network Printer."  *Somehow* the JetDirect sockets started to load from the "AppSocket/HP JetDirect." All resolved.  THANK YOU!